# Impact of a change in project level in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

How can I know the impact of a change in project level in Visual Studio? 
For example:
Project 1 has methods 1 and 2.
Project 2 references Project 1 in order to use only method 1.
If I make a change to method 2 of Project 1, is there a way for VS to tell me which projects are affected by this change?

Comment: I no longer have vs2010 installed but cannot you not just use "Find all References" option prior to making the change?

Comment: @QckLrner I agree with you, as an alternative you could use Resharper Refactor.